# Set static width cell not equal to string text

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

How to set static width cell and not equal to string size length in uicollectionview. I am using "sizeOfString" but how i increase the size width even if the text word is short length. Below is the swift code what i have tried

```
class EatTypeCell : UICollectionViewCell{
    @IBOutlet weak var lblTitle: UILabel!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.contentView.applyViewStyle(isRound: true, borderColor: UIColor.ColorGray, borderWidth: 1.5, backGroundColor: UIColor.ColorWhite)
        self.lblTitle.applyStyle(labelFont: UIFont.applySemiBold(fontSize: 11.5), textColor: UIColor.ColorGray)   
    }  
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let height = collectionView.frame.height/2 - 5
        var width : CGFloat = 0
        if self.colEat == collectionView {
            width = self.arrayMeal[indexPath.row].name.sizeOfString(font: UIFont.applySemiBold(fontSize: 11.5)).width + 40 // here width increases based on size of string
            
        }
        return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    }
```

Comment: @Sh_Khan problem is if the text length is small then cell width shows small even i put the size static. It is resizing based on text length

Comment: @Sh_Khan it is same as you can see above. Are you referring to main.storyboard?